# Regular Expression Java - check invoice number

Tags: java, regex

I need to build a regular expression for checking the invoice number like this: `FV/1024/02/2018`

- `FV` - using always FV nothing different
- `1024` - next numer of invoice - alway starting with "1" next three numbers are different `[0-9]`
- `02` - month - always on number 1-12
- `2018` - a year

i have:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([FV])/((1)[0-9]{3})/([0,1]{1}[0-9]{1})/([0-9]{4})");
```

and i know..."something" wrong ...

Comment: `[FV]` matches an `F` or a `V`.  If you want to match `FV`, use `FV` *without the square brackets*.  The meaning of `[ ... ]` is explained in the javadocs for `Pattern`.

Comment: You are going to have to be a little more specific with what exactly you need help with. Do you just need help matching a pattern from a large set of data or do you need to match something more specific?  Also include Java in your tag for the question or you are likely to get down voted. You should also use back ticks to make your line of code or indent by 4 spaces. Please also correct your grammar because it makes what you are asking unclear and hard to understand. All things that are likely to get you down voted.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
FV\/1\d{3}\/(:?(:?0[1-9])|1[0-2])\/\d{4}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QR5tcD/2/)

- `FV\/` matches first, constant part (`FV/`) string
- `1\d{3}\/` is an invoice number - starting with 1 and followed by 3 digits
- `(:?(:?0[1-9])|1[0-2])` is a month number

  - `(:?0[1-9])` from `01` to `09` OR
  - `1[1-2]` from `10` to `12`
- `\/\d{4}` is slash year, e.g. `/2018`

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
FV\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+
```

[Preview 1](https://regex101.com/r/eBF6N5/1)

or

```
FV\/(1[0-9]{3})\/([0,1]{1}[0-9]{1})\/([0-9]{4})
```

[Preview 2](https://regex101.com/r/eBF6N5/2)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (it matches your given invoice number: 'FV/1024/02/2018'):

```
FV\/(1[0-9]{3})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})
```

The Invoice Number, Month an Year each have their own Group.

---

[Demo Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/C5tW7q/1)